# Correlators $\langle \psi(z_1) \cdots \psi(z_N) \sigma(w_1) \sigma(w_2) \rangle$ in Ising conformal field theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, ising-model, quantum-hall-effect

Question: How one obtains
$$\langle \psi(z_1) \cdots \psi(z_N) \sigma(w_1) \sigma(w_2) \rangle \sim \mathrm{Pf}\left( \frac{f(z_i,z_j; w_1, w_2)}{z_i-z_j}\right) \prod_{i=1}^N (z_i-w_1)^{-1/2} (z_i-w_2)^{-1/2},$$
where $\mathrm{Pf}$ is the Pfaffian, $\psi$ is the neutral fermion and $\sigma$ is the spin field in the Ising conformal field theory, and
$$f(z_i,z_j;w_1,w_2) = (z_i-w_1)(z_j-w_2) + (z_j-w_1)(z_i-w_2).$$
The result appears in the [seminal paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.59.8084) of Read and Rezayi [see Eqs. (2.17) and (2.18)], discussing a new fractional quantum Hall phase (now called Read-Rezayi state). The paper states that the above correlator represents a two-quasihole wavefunction of Moore-Read state.

Note: I can evaluate the fermion correlators
$$\langle \psi(z_1) \cdots \psi(z_N) \rangle = \mathrm{Pf}\left( \frac{1}{z_i-z_j} \right)$$
using Wick's theorem. What I cannot understand is how one deals with the spin field $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

We proceed by using the bosonization formula. The square of the correlator is, after the bosonization,
$$\langle \psi(z_1) \cdots \psi(z_N) \sigma(w_1) \sigma(w_2) \rangle ^2 = \frac12 \langle b(z_1) \cdots b(z_N) \left( V_{\frac12}(w_1) V_{-\frac12}(w_2) + (-1)^N V_{-\frac12}(w_1) V_{\frac12}(w_2) \right) \rangle,$$
where $b(z) = -\partial \phi(z)$ is the U(1) current, and $V_\alpha(z) \sim e^{i \alpha \phi(z)}$ is the vertex operator. We used the fact that two Ising anyons should fuse to identity channel if $N$ is even, and to $\psi$ channel if $N$ is odd.

The left-hand side of the above equation should be proportional to, using the statement given in the question,
$$\det\left( \frac{f(z_i,z_j; w_1, w_2)}{z_i-z_j}\right) \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{z_i-w_1} \frac{1}{z_i-w_2},$$
where we used the fact that $\mathrm{Pf}\,(A)^2 = \det A$ for a matrix $A$. It remains to evaluate the right-hand side, but this can be done by using the Ward identity.